# error while adding a menu bar (missing classes with com.android.support:appcompat-v7:30 )

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, androidx, material-components-android

So, i try to add a menu in my activity, i did everything i read in a book, but i always get this error :

> The following classes could not be found:
>
> ```
> - android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
> - android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
> - android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
>  Tip: Try to build the project.   Tip: Try to refresh the layout.
> ```

my layout xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

in build:gradle (Mdoule:app), i implemented too library :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:30.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:30.0.0'
```

Comment: The support libraries v30 don't exist. You have to use androidx libraries and the material components library.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the support libraries v.30 **don't exist**.

> `//implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:30.0.0'`
>      `//implementation 'com.android.support:design:30.0.0'`

You have to use the androidx libraries and the material components library:

Use:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

and in your layout:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
  <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
      <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

      </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>
  </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```